# iOS5 - Setting the deployment target and building

Tags: deployment, ios5

I'm using iOS5 GM Seed and created an application using "story board" concept. Now I want to distribute the app to app store and want to set the deployment target to iOS4.2
The app when tested in simulator, its working fine.
When I'm building it for iOS device using development profile to test on device, its giving error: "Story boards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior"

How to resolve this issue and make my app run on ios4.2 as well.

Comment: XCode 4.2 is still pre-release, under NDA and not legal for developers to talk about just yet.  If you really can't wait to get an answer, you should ask this on devforums.apple.com where it is legal to talk about pre-release versions of Apple tools.

Comment: But GMSeed is already released and apple is already accepting apps in app store.

Comment: Has to wait until iOS 5.0 is officially and finally released.  On Apple's public mailing list, a modererator just razzed another developer who was asking about AVFoundation. http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Oct/msg00208.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Apple has officially release the XCode 4.2 :

Try closing the project and reopening it after switching to device from simulator.

Worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I still received the error.  However, the problem was identified and resolved in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781483/ios5-storyboard-error-storyboards-are-unavailable-on-ios-4-3-and-prior

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue today using XCode 4.2. Here is what I did to get it to build correctly:

1. Set Deployment and Build options back to 5.0.
2. Clean the project.
3. Close the project.
4. Quit XCode.
5. Restart XCode.
6. Debug / Build the project.

Comment: If only it were that simple! Doesn't work for me at all, I still get the error. :(

Answer (score 0):

I made it work! I do not know how it happened but in build settings, iOS deployment target settings was iOS 4.2 and that is why i got this issue. I set it back to iOS5.0 and nothing more required. It just got to work.

Answer (score 0):

You [officially can't do it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html) - *Storyboards are supported in iOS 5 and later and are enabled by default for new projects. If your app must run on earlier versions of iOS, though, you cannot use storyboards and should continue to use nib files*

Comment: Oh wow.. They changed that?! It was supposed to run on iOS 4 as well :(