# Static Grouped UITableView without storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been searching and can't find an answer anywhere. I want to a create a really simple grouped table view for "settings" of my app. User taps a button and I want to load a UITableView that has 3 or 4 cells in categories. Is there a way to just set one up in IB without the dynamic code building (ie. cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Note: Most answers I have found pertain to storyboard, which I am not using.

Comment: This feature is only available through storyboards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use static cells in UITableView without using Storyboards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041272/how-to-use-static-cells-in-uitableview-without-using-storyboards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is the way a table gets its data -- there's no way to populate a table without that in iOS (in OSX you can use bindings, but they're not available in iOS).

If you only need a few cells, are you sure you need to use a table?

Comment: @Dustin, yeah, that was my thought too -- he could use buttons and labels that would give a look similar to a grouped table view.

Comment: Main reason I want to use a table, and tableViewCells is because I want to have UISwitch's on the accessory part of the cell

Comment: @Spartan9209, then you just need to use tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: the 2 required methods in the UITableViewDataSource protocol.