# Using single storyboard views for static table view in iOS5+ instead of using storyboards for the entire app?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uistoryboard

Recently I was searching for an useful approach for static table views without using storyboards for my entire app. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041693/66414):

> Static table view cells are only available when using storyboards. However, if you aren't using storyboards for your entire UI you can still use them for individual screens instead of a collection of strings.
>
> To do this you can create a UIStoryboard file with a single view controller on it that has it's File's Owner set to your custom view controller subclass. Set the VC's identifier to some value. When you want to display this, get the storyboard and then instantiate your view controller subclass by creating the VC from your storyboard.

Is it a good approach? Or is it better to implement it [the iOS4 way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728293/66414)?

What should be preferred in case of performance and maintainable code base?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining code base is pretty easy in Storyboard for static pages.

Comment: Yes, but is it useful to mix xib and storyboard files for this usage?

Comment: Yes, it is better than iOS4 way you mentioned.