# xcode6 static tableview in xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make a view controller with view in separate XIB file.

If I add `tableview` then I couldn't specify cell type (static or dynamic):
[image]

But if I add tableview to storyboard - everything works as expected:
[image]

Is it xcode6 bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static table view cells are only available when using storyboards. Take a look at this answer:
[How to use static cells in UITableView without using Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041272/how-to-use-static-cells-in-uitableview-without-using-storyboards)