# Adding Static Cells to UITableView in Interface Builder for iOS8? Content Section Not Shown

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to add static cells to a UITableView in XCode 6 using Interface Builder. All the tutorials I am seeing online show a section called "Content" which allows the cells to be made static. Also, there is a feature to switch the number of sections.

I have screenshots below for both.

This is the first, with the feature:

[image: This is the first.]

This is the second, without the feature:
[image: This is the second.]

I could probably figure this out, but I'm wondering why the problem is happening. The one with the feature is from an older version of iOS and is placed inside a storyboard. The one without the feature is from the newest version of iOS and XCode, and is in a .xib file, without a view controller in the file.

I'm thinking this may be an issue with the new XCode, but I'd love to hear why. I'm really needing to make these static cells, and all the answers I've found on the internet seem to assume that this section is available.

Answer (score 10):

Dynamic prototype and static cells are only available in storyboard table views.

Comment: See "Loading Table View Cells From A Storyboard" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 0):

Static table view cells are only available when using storyboards. However, if you aren't using storyboards for your entire UI you can still use them for individual screens instead of a collection of screens.
Please see this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041693/3683148