# Is it possible to subclass UITableViewController with xib or storyboard?

Tags: ios

It is easy to subclass UITableView. Also my UITableViewController can inherit BaseTableViewController programmatically instead of xib. But the requirement is using xib or sb to subclass. Is it possible? I have tried to drag a UITableViewController in a xib. And Xcode remind me the customization only can be done in storyboard.But in storyboard , children controllerA is connected to its parent controller. And children controllerA inherit from baseController. BaseController needn't to connect anything with  segue. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static table view cells are only available when using storyboards. Take a look at this answer: [How to use static cells in UITableView without using Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041272/how-to-use-static-cells-in-uitableview-without-using-storyboards)