# Storyboard or XIB for iphone app development, which one should I pick?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I have a project whose release date is Q1 2013, should I use xib to get compatibility to iOS4.3 and early version, or should I just use storyboard to ignore iOS4.3 and early version users? I have checked some ios version share data, and just want to know you guys' opinions.
http://www.14oranges.com/2012/07/ios-version-statistics-%E2%80%93-july-14th-2012/

Comment: Regarding to that statistic (and if this one is really true) I would suggest to ignore ios4.x and use Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with them I guess. I personally feel like xibs give you more power over a custom interface but that may just be because I'm used to them (I'm sure everything that can be done in xibs can be done in storyboards as well).

Storyboards will probably make the entire development process easier, seeing as though you can throw together a navigation or table view controller in a matter of a couple seconds. More details on perks of storyboards [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084124/716216).

Additionally, if you're worried about backwards compatibility before you start the project you should compile a summary of all the features of iOS that you wish to use. From this you can extrapolate which iOS devices/iOS versions will be able to run your app. Doing this should give you a clear idea of how far back you're able to support and should help make the 4.3+- decision easier.

Comment: for me, the problem is I have already wrote code for a while using storyboard. Then, a friend told me that storyboard can't run in ios4.3 and early version. So i get a choice to make: convert my app using xib rewrite, or drop the users run ios4.3 and early version. So I want to know whether the rewrite work is worth doing or not, surely it depends on how many users are there using ios4.3 and early version.