# Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I recently downloaded [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 5 DP to test my apps in iOS 7. The first thing I noticed and confirmed is that my view's bounds is not always resized to account for the status bar and navigation bar.

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I print the view's bounds:

> {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}

This results in my content appearing below the navigation bar and status bar.

I know I could account for the height myself by getting the main screen's height, subtracting the status bar's height and navigation bar's height, but that seems like unnecessary extra work.

How can I fix this issue?

**Update:**

I've found a solution for this specific problem. Set the navigation bar's translucent property to NO:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

This will fix the view from being framed underneath the navigation bar and status bar.

However, I have not found a fix for the case when you want the navigation bar to be translucent. For instance, viewing a photo full screen, I wish to have the navigation bar translucent, and the view to be framed underneath it. That works, but when I toggle showing/hiding the navigation bar, I've experienced even stranger results. The first subview (a UIScrollView) gets its bounds y origin changed every time.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue in xcode 5 DP

Comment: Could you tell me why navigation bar back button always showing with blue text???

Comment: Look in the navigation bar for a tint color property, you should be able to change that blue color to whatever you want.

Comment: I hate ios upgrading sometimes because Apple never gave you a opportunity to keep your app backwards compatible.

Comment: @beebcon put your update as an answer and accept that as the answer to help others

Comment: If the problem is related to the view going under the status bar after hiding the navigation controller top bar I would refer to the answer by @Stunner http://stackoverflow.com/a/18976660/235206 as the solution

Comment: Thanks for this, wish I would have found 8 hours ago... FWIW, a New install of my App does not have this problem, but upgrading my app does.. weird ios7 $#!+

Comment: doesnt when presenting modalviewcontrollers

Answer (score 498, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing a new property called `edgesForExtendedLayout` in iOS7 SDK. Please add the following code to achieve this,

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

You need to add the above in your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method.

> iOS 7 brings several changes to how you layout and customize the
>   appearance of your *UI*. The changes in view-controller layout, tint
>   color, and font affect all the *UIKit* objects in your app. In
>   addition, enhancements to gesture recognizer APIs give you finer
>   grained control over gesture interactions.
>
> **Using View Controllers**
>
> In iOS 7, view controllers use full-screen layout. At the same time,
>   iOS 7 gives you more granular control over the way a view controller
>   lays out its views. In particular, the concept of full-screen layout
>   has been refined to let a view controller specify the layout of each
>   edge of its view.
>
> The `wantsFullScreenLayout` view controller property is deprecated in
>   iOS 7. If you currently specify `wantsFullScreenLayout = NO`, the view
>   controller may display its content at an unexpected screen location
>   when it runs in iOS 7.
>
> To adjust how a view controller lays out its views, `UIViewController`
>   provides the following properties:
>
> - **edgesForExtendedLayout**
>
> The `edgesForExtendedLayout` property uses the `UIRectEdge` type,
>   which specifies each of a rectangle’s four edges, in addition to
>   specifying none and all. Use `edgesForExtendedLayout` to specify which
>   edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar translucency. By
>   default, the value of this property is `UIRectEdgeAll`.
>
> - **extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars**
>
> If your design uses opaque bars, refine `edgesForExtendedLayout` by
>   also setting the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property to
>   **NO**. (The default value of `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is **NO**.)
>
> - **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets**
>
> If you don’t want a scroll view’s content insets to be automatically
>   adjusted, set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to **NO**. (The
>   default value of `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is **YES**.)
>
> - **topLayoutGuide, bottomLayoutGuide**
>
> The `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` properties indicate the
>   location of the top or bottom bar edges in a view controller’s view.
>   If bars should overlap the top or bottom of a view, you can use
>   Interface Builder to position the view relative to the bar by creating
>   constraints to the bottom of `topLayoutGuide` or to the top of
>   bottomLayoutGuide. (If no bars should overlap the view, the bottom of
>   `topLayoutGuide` is the same as the top of the view and the top of
>   `bottomLayoutGuide` is the same as the bottom of the view.) Both
>   properties are lazily created when requested.

Please refer, [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1)

Comment: It will not compile under iOS6. I think it should be written as performselector...

Comment: Yes, Thats why I have included the selector check with if condition, if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])

Comment: I tried it… But using this method changes all my bars from white to gray… Is there a solution?

Comment: @Julian set your window color to your view background color, i.e.: [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: This would not work if I have no navigation bar. In that case, my view is extends behind the status bar..

Comment: I have the same problem as @VanDuTran. edgesForExtendedLayout does not help if the navigation bar is hidden.

Comment: Also, this text is copied from the Apple documentation, which is very far from clear. Can somebody explain in understandable words what all these options do?

Comment: If the problem is related to the view going under the status bar after hiding the navigation controller top bar I would refer to the answer by @Stunner stackoverflow.com/a/18976660/235206 as the solution

Comment: I did everything suggested: no change. The status bar is always shown translucent and also popup views show after the status bar

Comment: I had an issue trying to use this solution. It was resolved by making sure I was in an Xcode 5.0 storyboard and had View as set to iOS 7.0 and later in the file inspector for the storyboard. If you have it set to an earlier version of Xcode, you won't get the new layout functionality.

Comment: it works but ... there is no longer translucent effect... how can we preserve translucent effect as well...

Comment: adding this piece of code in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{ did the trick for me

Comment: Great answer! Btw, the code in swift is `if(self.respondsToSelector(Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout"))) { self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None }`

Comment: what about in iOS 8?

Answer (score 112):

You don't have to calculate how far to shift everything down, there's a build in property for this. In Interface Builder, highlight your view controller, and then navigate to the attributes inspector. Here you'll see some check boxes next to the words "Extend Edges". As you can see, in the first screenshot, the default selection is for content to appear under top and bottom bars, but not under opaque bars, which is why setting the bar style to not translucent worked for you.

As you can somewhat see in the first screenshot, there are two UI elements hiding below the navigation bar. (I've enabled wireframes in IB to illustrate this) These elements, a UIButton and a UISegmentedControl both have their "y" origin set to zero, and the view controller is set to allow content below the top bar.

[image]

This second screenshot shows what happens when you deselect the "Under Top Bars" check box. As you can see, the view controllers view has been shifted down appropriately for its y origin to be right underneath the navigation bar.

[image]

This can also be accomplished programmatically through the usage of `-[UIViewController edgesForExtendedLayout]`. Here's a link to the class reference for [edgeForExtendedLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout), and for [UIRectEdge](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIRectEdge)

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
```

Comment: How do I do the same for just view in a .xib?

Comment: I added one label on view and I followed your instruction but this is not working for me

Comment: @bobics The answer to the XIB question is, "You can't." Not through IB anyway. File a radar and hope Apple eventually addresses it.

Comment: Thanks @0x7fffffff, This was just the info I was looking for and was very helpful.

Answer (score 33):

I created my view programmatically and this ended up working for me:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // only works for iOS 7+
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;

        // snaps the view under the status bar (iOS 6 style)
        viewBounds.origin.y = topBarOffset * -1;

        // shrink the bounds of your view to compensate for the offset
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height + (topBarOffset * -1);
        self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/UIViewController_Class.pdf) (in **topLayoutGuide** section at bottom of pg.39).

Comment: Finally found an answer that actually works for this. Good work!

Comment: To solve the problem whereby the view controller's view shows up under the status bar when the navigation bar is hidden, this is the code which snaps the view under the status bar.

Comment: Note: this will push the bottom of your view off the screen.

Comment: Also, unless you are building for _only_ iOS7, the above code will throw an error - `topLayoutGuide` is iOS7 only.

Comment: Thank you, you just save me for 2 hours of plain GUI code nightmare! This work like magic

Comment: Put this as condition , so it will not crash on iOS 6.0
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])

Comment: I have a issue with this code, I have table view inside the view and after applying this code table view goes beyond the bound.

Comment: As mentioned by AnswerBot, this code will push the bottom of your view offscreen. You'll need to compensate for that by modifying the height of your table view.

Comment: Also note that when your main view is a UITableView the viewDidLayoutSubviews will get called on each scroll. Your UITableView will be scaled down until its height is 15px. Add a flag to only run this code once. ;)

Comment: @Stunner why don't you change the frame instead of bounds ?

Comment: You can change the frame as well and it will work. The reason I changed the bounds is because I ended up using the code snippet Apple provided, and that already used bounds, so I worked with that. See the source link I provided.

Comment: Grate!!! it's working fine in both iOS6 & iOS 7 but I have seen my UIToolBar shirting bottom to top for with some color in iOS 7 for 2 seconds. any suggestions??  Thank you

Answer (score 32):

Swift 3 / Swift 4 solution that also works with NIBs/XIB files in iOS 10+:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    edgesForExtendedLayout = []
}
```

Comment: This is What Helped me... So Simple. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you it's really helpful

Comment: This is the best solution for 10.x Swift 3+ IMO

Answer (score 10):

If you want the view to have the translucent nav bar (which is kind of nice) you have to setup a contentInset or similar.

Here is how I do it:

```
// Check if we are running on ios7
if([[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue] >= 7) {
      CGRect statusBarViewRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
      float heightPadding = statusBarViewRect.size.height+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

      myContentView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(heightPadding, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: why can't you directly compare it with 7.0

Comment: lol I get it: checking against a specific version with minor added is less robust. But you are checking if the value is BIGGER or equal to so comparing to 7.0 would do just fine here ;)

Comment: @leena - This is features in 7.x and later - so I check if the version is 7 or greater and skip the minor revisions in the check.

Comment: I Had an issue with my tableView beeing displayed behind my Tabbar. Which made the last row of my table never to scroll above the Tabbar. I fixed it like that:                                                      myTableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0.0, TabbarHeight, 0)

Comment: `contentInset` is a property of `UIScrollView`. What if my main view is not a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Then how would I fix the overlap problem?

Comment: BOOL ios7 = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemMajorVersion] == 7;

Comment: This is the best solution for my purpose. To make it better, collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets should be set too. And translucent is meaningless under most circumstances if the view is not a scrollView.

Answer (score 9):

In your apps plist file add a row, call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to *NO*.

Answer (score 9):

`edgesForExtendedLayout` does the trick for iOS 7. However, if you build the app across iOS 7 SDK and deploy it in iOS 6, the navigation bar appears translucent and the views go beneath it. So, to fix it for both iOS 7 as well as for iOS 6 do this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;   // iOS 7 specific
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest trick is to open the [NIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) file and do these two simple steps:

1. Just toggle that and set it to the one you prefer:

[image]

2. Select those UIView's/UIIMageView's/... that you want to be moved down. In my case only the logo was overlapped an I've set the delta to +15; (OR -15 if you chose iOS 7 in step 1)

[image]

And **the result**:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: It works, but this look like a hard to maintain solution. It would be best to just fix the problem instead of patching it.

Comment: it would be best to do it programmatically for all view's subviews because it doesn't work if applied to main view

Answer (score 5):

Swift Solution:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
}
```

Comment: This is now edgesForExtendedLayout = []

Comment: Since this is a public answer we shouldn't forget to call: `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 4):

I would like to expand on Stunner's answer, and add an `if` statement to check if it is iOS-7, because when I tested it on iOS 6 my app would crash.

The addition would be adding:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
```

So I would suggest adding this method to your `MyViewControler.m` file:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
        viewBounds.origin.y = topBarOffset * -1;
        self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a scenario where I use the BannerViewController written by Apple to display my ads and a ScrollViewController embedded in the BannerViewController.

To prevent the navigation bar from hiding my content, I had to make two changes.

1) Modify BannerViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
   if (systemVersion >= 7.0) {
      self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
   }
}
```

2) Modify my ScrollViewContoller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (systemVersion >= 7.0) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;
    }
}
```

Now the ads show up correctly at the bottom of the view instead of being covered by the Navigation bar and the content on the top is not cut off.

Answer (score 2):

just set the following code in view will appear.

```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<= 7) {
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked in my circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

make a constraints to Top Layout like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2 - Xcode 10.0 - iOS 12.0:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {} else {
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
  self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the key "View Controller-based status bar appearance" from the dropdownlist as a row in `info.plist`. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: interesting.it helped on my cocos2d projects.as I toggle this option I can see the top status bar is completely has gone or appear.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the simplest solution is to add two keys into the plist

[image]

Comment: +1, I had the "Status bar initially hidden"=YES, but when adding "View controller-based status bar appearance"=NO I got rid of the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my app by iPads (armv7, armv7s, amr64) only by presenting another UIViewController and after dismiss them goes nav bar under status bar...
I spend a lot of time to find any solution for that. I'm using storyboard and in InterfaceBuilder for UIViewController which makes terrible i set Presentation from FullScreen -> Current Context and it fix this issue. It works in my app only for iPads => iOS8.0 (testing with iOS8.1) and for iPads with iOS 7.1 not work!! [image: see screenshot]

Comment: In my case, my main view was overlapping my tabBar and I had no Idea why. It turns out the  Extend Edges > Under Bottom Bars was checked. It was really hard to notice it because the background of my app was white and it only generated some level opacity over my tabBar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Steps For Hide the status bar in iOS 7:

1.Go to your application info.plist file.

2.And Set, View controller-based status bar appearance : Boolean NO

Hope i solved the status bar issue.....

Answer (score 0):

In my case having loadView() interrupted
this code:
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone

but after deleting loadView() everything worked fine