# Autolayout view fill parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

I have next configuration:

UIView (just for some shadows) > UIScrollView (just for bouncing) > UIView (actual content view).

How can I setup Autolayout so that all three views takes all available free space, but no more?

If I have something like "Single view template" layout everything is fine, but, how can I make autolayout respect Navigation bar and Tab Bar? My view always gets bigger than real available size and gets covered by Tab Bar.

Comment: Define exactly what you want when you say you want them to take all space. Do they all have the same height? Same width? Is one of them variable height/width? Are they aligned horizontally/vertically? etc... A diagram of what you want will make it much easier.

Comment: Ok, I have navigation controller inside of tab bar controller. When I have one UIView, it fits empty space fine. When I wrap that UIView in UIScrollView, scroll view become taller than it should be, spreads under tab bar and so do child UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Just Set it like

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

And you want also that no one give take other view space then you can achieve this way

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does it disable autolayout? Or autoresizing mask can coexist with Autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

See [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7). 
The gist is have in viewDidLoad for iOS 7:

*self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;*