# iOS 7 status bar overlaps with the tool bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, toolbar

This question has been asked so many times but I am not able to fix this issue. Here is the problem:

- I have a xib file with many views in it. I am using toolbar. When I show the status bar it overlaps with the toolbar.
- I can edit view's frame because its disable.
- I have tried this in appdelegate

  ```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
      [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
      self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
      self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
  }
  ```

but it didn't work.

There are so many views in xib file. It's hard to resize each frames.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for) ? You have to reset each view and if you don't want to take this hard step then hide status bar.

Comment: Parent view's frame is not editable. I can't change its y to 20px.

Comment: You have to reset all your subviews.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for?lq=1.

Comment: You need to set Delta in xib for Toolbar. It will fix ur issue.

Comment: delta y? just need to change delta value not the view's origin and height?