# In iOS6 the bottom of the screen gets cut

Tags: ios, iphone, layout

I have a `UIWebView` build in Xcode 5, I load a page with a form, but the bottom of the screen is cut, if I enter a text in the form and press "done" the bottom of the screen appears again but the top of the screen is cut now.

I'm work with xcode5, builds for iOs 6 and later and view as iOs7 and later.

The problem happens only with iPhone 4 -iOS6 but it work fine with iPhone 4&5 with iOS7.

[Image 1: Bottom screen is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxGym.png)

Then I enter text in the first field and press "done" and....

[Image 2: Top screen is missing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5Uhm.png) (and bottom is ok)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: OK,i post 2 images... thanks

Comment: The iOS 6 screen is effectively 20 pixels shorter than the iOS 7 screen, since iOS 7 makes the status bar a part of your screen while iOS 6 does not.  There are a number of different ways to deal with this, depending on your particular design.

Answer (score 0):

In your .xib file I assume that you do not use Autolayout. Navigate to the size inspector tab (the one with the ruler) and set the Delta Y property to -20.

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for) for screenshots regarding these settings.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, i made the change and the bottom problem was fixed.... but now the top of the screen missed (as in the image 2), before and after I enter text... what do you think is the problem? Thanks Again!!