# GUI elements position in Xcode Storyboard differs from their position in the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I recently worked with Xcode, especially with layout GUI elements. I read a lot of questions here about this, but it did not help me. What I have: ViewController, it lies ImageView, it lay all the other elements, I disable autolayout, screen size and in the simulator and in Xcode - the same (4 inches), but when I run I still see it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, what is there is a way to what looks like a storyboard, and looked in the simulator (and real device) equally?

Answer (score 3):

There might be two issues you are suffering with, please check following points for better understanding.

- Check this with iOS 6 simulator. If its working fine then, you need to set ios 6/7 deltas for your subviews. Here is better explanation of it-- [Interface Builder: What are the UIView's Layout iOS 6/7 Deltas for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for)
- Check autoresizing masks of your subviews, definitely this is what affecting your views.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in your Storyboard view, you have not displayed a status bar and that when running on the simulator, a status bar is shown. This is why all the objects are off placed. To fix this, you can **either**:

**Hide the Status Bar** - Call this method in your desired view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

**Show a simulated metric** - Switch on the status bar simulated metric in your Storyboard:

[image]