# Buttons on bottom disappear with auto layout and Constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, constraints, autolayout

i'm transitioning my app to iOS7, and adding autolayout feature with 65 constraints pixel from top get my bottom buttons disappear. Why? i've only added 65px constraint to the massive view, but if i remove it and only add "autolayout" feature they will disappear anyway.

[image]

Comment: remove the old constraints

Comment: I think it gets confused if you try to user auto layout and constraints! Once you add one constraint, my recommendation would be to constrain everything that you want to fix the position of. Just constrain the two buttons to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a constraint to bottom instead of top =)
GL HF

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Delta of your view controller. Switch Story board to ios6.1 or later from utility area (1st item). Then select view of your Vc and in size inspector menu in utility area there will be delta section below frame. There will be triangle before every delta. Triangle y to 64 (you should be on ios6.1 or later of your storyboard).

If you need help on Deltas visit : Interface Builder: 
[Interface Builder: What are the UIView's Layout iOS 6/7 Deltas for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for)