# iOS 7 custom transition issues

Tags: ios, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to implement some custom transitions on the iPad but I am getting some issues. Since the x, y coordinates do not always start on the upper left corner in the `containerView` of the `transitionContext` when the device is rotated I wrote the following methods

```
- (CGRect)rectForPresentedStateStart:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    
    switch (fromViewController.interfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return CGRectMake(0, containerView.bounds.size.height,
                              containerView.bounds.size.width, containerView.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return CGRectMake(0, - containerView.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3,
                              containerView.bounds.size.height, containerView.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return CGRectMake(- containerView.bounds.size.width * 2 / 3, 0,
                              containerView.bounds.size.width * 2 / 3, containerView.bounds.size.height);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            return CGRectMake(containerView.bounds.size.width, 0,
                              containerView.bounds.size.width * 2 / 3, containerView.bounds.size.height);
        default:
            return CGRectZero;
    }

}

- (CGRect)rectForPresentedStateEnd:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

    
    switch (toViewController.interfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return CGRectOffset([self rectForPresentedStateStart:transitionContext], 0, - containerView.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return CGRectOffset([self rectForPresentedStateStart:transitionContext], 0, containerView.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return CGRectOffset([self rectForPresentedStateStart:transitionContext], containerView.bounds.size.width * 2 / 3, 0);
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            return CGRectOffset([self rectForPresentedStateStart:transitionContext], - containerView.bounds.size.width * 2 / 3, 0);
        default:
            return CGRectZero;
    }
}
```

On portrait mode and upside down everything seems to work fine. The issue is on landscape.

1. When the devices orientation is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` the view disappears for a second just before the transition starts.
2. When the devices orientation is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` I get the following issue: The navigation bar is smaller and turns to normal when the transition ends like in the pictures

[image: Issue with navigation bar when transition occurs]

*Issue with navigation bar when transition occurs*

[image: After transition is completed]

*After transition is completed*

I am not sure if these are bugs from apple or if I am doing something wrong and if so how can I fix the issues?

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for

Comment: @Spynet I tried changing it in my table view but unfortunately without any change

Comment: still it looks same or some extra behaviour….

Comment: @Spynet looks exactly the same. And it looks also the same when I use the autolayout

Comment: can u explain little bit more do u have 2 tables or 1 and

Comment: on the test project I just have one table and create a new instance of it when a cell is being clicked. On my main project I have 2 but I get the same behaviour

Comment: if 2 tables means why 1 have adobt the delta value why not adopt the second….

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57481/discussion-between-alecnash-and-spynet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely an apple bug. For presenting the animation I am using something like this:

```
if (self.presenting) {
        toViewController.view.frame = [self rectForPresentedStateStart:transitionContext];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            fromViewController.view.frame = [self rectForDismissedState:transitionContext];
            toViewController.view.frame = [self rectForPresentedStateEnd:transitionContext];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];    
}
```

The problem with the navigation controller is fixed if I add the view (            `[transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];`
) after the `animateWithDuration` method. Still cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your `containerView`  is `UIWindow`. So it's bounds is orientation independent so `containerView.bounds.size.height` is the same in portrait and landscape.

If I'm right you need to use width as height and height as width in landscape

Comment: Not exactly. It's not like UIWindow. The axis doesn't stay put in the upper left corner when rotating. So everything should be adjusted accordingly.