# Auto Layout with UITabBarController

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to shift to Auto Layout in my app, but I'm having some trouble with my `UITabBarController`. Basically, I have two buttons on my home screen, and I want them to have equal sizes, one 50 pixels from the top of the screen and one 50 pixels from the bottom.

The issue is that when I do this:

```
NSArray* verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-
    [buttonOne(150)]" options:0 metrics:nil 
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(buttonOne)];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];

verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:
    [buttonTwo(==buttonOne)]-50-|" options:0 metrics:nil 
    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(buttonOne, buttonTwo)];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

The bottom button is 50 pixels from the bottom of the view, which is 568 points tall, when the height of `self.view` should be the screen height minus the tab bar's height (the navigation bar is hidden). The majority of this padding is eaten up by the height of the tab bar.

**My questions is: Why is my view controller's view not resizing so that it doesn't count the space *under* my tab bar as part of its height?**

Comment: See [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion would be to make sure you adding your constraints to a container and not a top level view.  ie.  Add a view under the top level view and add components to that.  My guess is that there are some autoresizing contraints on the top level view

Answer (score 0):

I think railwayparade is correct. I implemented a UITabBar/UITabBarController replacement  using auto-layout, it's called [GGTabBar](http://github.com/goles/GGTabBar). I also wrote a pretty comprehensive [Blog Post](https://nicolasgoles.com/blog/2014/06/exploring-auto-layout-with-a-uitabbar-replacement/) about how I approached the problem, and how did I use Auto Layout to solve it.