# navigation controller bar is being cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

If hiding the status bar by choosing `status bar style = hide during application launch` and I am customizing uinavigation bar like the following

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar-iphone.png"]
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and when I am  getting this : the navigation bar is cut off the top.

[image]

and

[image]

Any ideas about this situation and how to fix it ?

Comment: You can try  `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Comment: have you tried?. it is not working.

Comment: no i look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7

Comment: you can try self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; in viewcontroller

Comment: might be you navigation image *navbar-iphone.png* half transparent? what is you actuly NavBar image can you attach with question?

Comment: I too have similar problem. It appears only when presenting view controller and works perfectly when pushed.

Comment: mine is another way around. it is being cut off when push and works well when presenting modal view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

during application launch. here viewController is UINavigationController.

```
//set status bar hidden true.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES]; 

//You can set navigation bar frame to start from 0.0,0.0
    self.viewController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.viewController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0, -20.0);

//set the image u want.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar-iphone.png"]
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES]; 
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar-iphone.png"]
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.viewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```