# Presenting view controller on IOS 7 navigation bar issue

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have downloaded Xcode 5 GM seed and trying to run my application on it.

I have set a black image for navigation bar which works perfectly on iOS 7.

But whenever I present a view controller the navigation bar image does not get set properly. It is showing a patch.

Code :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-nav-bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Has anyone encountered the same issue ?

**EDIT :**
I have similar problem as the link below. *But in my case, it appears only when presenting view controller and works perfectly when pushed.*

> [navigation controller bar is being cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778064/navigation-controller-bar-is-being-cut-off?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to becareful about the following:

**tintColor** is the bar buttons and title color:

```
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whitColor];
```

**barTintColor** is the bar background color:

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:12.0/255.0 blue:19.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

**translucent**, It is `YES` by default in iOS7 :

`navigationBar.translucent = NO`;

Take a look at the below image from Apple:

[image]

Comment: Ok but that dude hides the statusbar which is a very bad idea, I think your problem is with the translucent and the image height, set translucent to NO, and I think your bar bg image will be 22px more in height.

Comment: bar bg image works perfectly when it is pushed. But it causes problem when presented. I tried your solution but no luck..