# UITextView setContentOffset with scrollEnabled=NO in iOS7

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, ios7

I have an autoscroll feature in my app. When it's activated, my code disables textView scroll and changes contentOffset using `CADisplayLink`.

Works fine in earlier versions of iOS, but in 7th text appears cropped.

While discovered further I've found that `contentSize` being changed some time after I disable scroll of textView. Looks like it some kind of optimization. But it don't take `contentOffset` into account.

To reproduce this bug:

1. Make sure text in textView is large enough, at least two pages in size.
2. In ViewController put `_textView.scrollEnabled = NO;` into `-viewDidLoad`
3. In ViewController add:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
       [_textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 400) animated:YES];
   }
   ```

**The question is: how to autoscroll `UITextView` in iOS7 while `scrollEnabled` set to `NO`?**

*Scroll is disabled to stop possible `UITextView` built-in autoscroll on caret position change and to disallow user interaction with control.*

Comment: I feel this is due to the new iOS7 full screen layout design. Please refer my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7/18785646#18785646. That will be helpful...

Comment: @Nandha, thanks for your comment. Yes, I know about that new UIViewController properties, and checked them too. But result is the same.

Answer (score 4):

If your text is cropped in the bottom while scrollEnabled is NO:

```
self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The other answer doesn't preserve margins in  all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't exactly solve the issue, but as a work around, you can allowing scrolling to be enabled, but set UserInteractionEnabled to NO.

```
[_textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: now that is what i was looking for...5 stars for you brother

Comment: except now you can't type into it