# image position iOS 7 vs iOS 6

Tags: uiimageview, backwards-compatibility, ios7

I have a background image issue for my app after I updated the project for iOS 7.
The app is navigation controller managed. I have a background image (UIImageView) created in IB. Since I place it a bit under the navigation menu I assume that the placement is calculated from the top of the view which in iOS 7 is beneath the Navigation Controller. When I run the app in iOS 6 the image is quite far down on the screen. Once again I assume this is because the top of the view in iOS 6 is below the Navigation Controller menu.

How do I fix so that the image has the same vertical distance from the navigation controller in iOS7 and iOS6?

Best regards

Frederik

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 brings several changes to how you lay out and customize the appearance of your UI. The changes in view-controller layout, tint color, and font affect all the UIKit objects in your app. In addition, enhancements to gesture recognizer APIs give you finer grained control over gesture interactions.

Please refer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7/18785646#18785646).

Answer (score 0):

One solution what I did is : I hooked background image to a reference from my xib, and set the frame programmatically from ViewDidLoad. It works fine.Please note that not forget to check iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 and set height to 568 and 480 respectively.