# How can I make my UINavigationBar totally transparent on iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm working on making an application iOS7-compatible, and I'm encountering a problem with UINavigationBar that's driving me crazy:

**I want to make my navigationBar totally transparent, without any blur or backgroundPicture, but containing and displaying navigationItem buttons.**

In iOS6, I used to make that this way:

```
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent_image.png"]
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But it doesn't work anymore on iOS7.

**Any suggestions ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7) will answer your question? If you select your view controller and then uncheck the box next to "extend edges under top bars", the background image won't bleed underneath it.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, I should use storyboard to try your suggestion, and unfortunately I use Xib files...

Would you have any other suggestion compatible with that ?

Comment: From the same link, you could paste this code in the viewDidLoad method: if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation MyCustomNavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    [self setupBackground];
}

- (void)setupBackground {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // make navigation bar overlap the content
    self.translucent = YES; 
    self.opaque = NO;

    // remove the default background image by replacing it with a clear image
    [self setBackgroundImage:[self.class maskedImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // remove defualt bottom shadow
    [self setShadowImage: [UIImage new]]; 
}

+ (UIImage *)maskedImage {
    const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-white-pixel-bg.jpg"];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];
}

@end
```