# iOS 7 status bar and self.view.frame and self.view.bounds

Tags: xcode, ios6, uiview, ios7, statusbar

I recently released an iOS6 app, and I need to update it for iOS 7. The new status bar is a bit of an issue. The frame/bounds of self.view seem to have changed (+20 points) and I use self.view.bounds to determine the placement of some elements. I have been looking at some solutions. Basically I need to update the app while still supporting the iOS 6 status bar. Is there a best practice for this?

The code below seems to work to detect an iOS 7 device and shift the content into position, but also causes other issues. Anyway I am not confident that this is the best way.

```
if([[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect statusBarViewRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    float heightPadding = statusBarViewRect.size.height+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

    [myContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, heightPadding, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - heightPadding)];
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this by implementing new property called edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7 SDK. Please add the following code to achieve this,

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

You need add the above code in your -(void)viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks! But self.view bounds and frame height is 568 whether or not I use this code. I assume that these numbers should be 548 and the frame  origin should be 0, 20?

Comment: this code will make the frame height to 548 from 568. The above code will only execute in iOS7.

Comment: @Nandha yes its working fine for me. but my app have Tabbacontroller alos. Rest of the viewcontroller is working fine. Issue in Tabbar view controller. suppose i have 5 tab. 1. when i click on tab (List screen open) it working fine when i click on list detail open fine. up to yet its working fine 2. when i click on tab 2 (another list) open. that time when i clickon tab1 than detail screen main view frame decrease to 64px. i have tried to forcefully increase but not working .. what can i do in this case ??

Comment: I have two apps with very similar code, this works on one but not the other and I haven't been able to figure out why. On one, self.view.bounds.size.height is 548, on the other it's 568.

Comment: This solution will work if you have navigation or tool bar at top. If you have plain view without any view, it won't work. For that you need different solution if you need refer my old question it has solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution to adjust my view in a modal dialog:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        CGRect sbFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        __block CGRect vFrame = self.view.frame;
        __block CGFloat diff = sbFrame.size.height + sbFrame.origin.y - vFrame.origin.y;
        if (diff > 0.0)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                                  delay:0.0
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 vFrame.origin.y += diff;
                                 vFrame.size.height -= diff;
                                 self.view.frame = vFrame;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 NSLog(@"Done!");
                             }];
        }
    }
}
```