# Elements in ios 7 shifted down for 20 points

Tags: ios, ios7, iphone-5, iphone-4

I ran my program on iphone 4 and 5 emulator with ios 7 and suddenly by background and some element on the screen became shifted down. I measured and it equals to 20 points. My view doesn't use auto layout.
Why it is so ? how to fix?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: Thank you! Found answer in this link

Answer (score 0):

It's because in iOS 7, the status bar area at the top where the battery etc are shown is now a usable area.

This was not the case in iOS6 which is why your app has moved down.

You will need to decide how how want to approach this problem.

Maybe extend your background up by 20 points and has it be displayed underneath the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's because now in iOS7 status bar is not consuming space of 20pixel. so now your view become larger. you can do code with this condition

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int versionVal=[currSysVer intValue];
if(versionVal>=7)
{
     //code iOS7 
}
```