# Why is my UITableView cut off in iOS 7?

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, ios7

In iOS 6, my login tableview that consisted of two rows (Username and Password) was completely shown correctly. In iOS 7, the bottom row is cut off, and I don't know why or how to correct the issue. Nothing changed except for upgrading to Xcode 5 and running on the iOS 7 simulator.

[image]

UPDATE: adding more images

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you creating the table view?  How are you positioning it?  You may need to show some code.

Comment: I have added my cellforrowatindexpath method, but adding the table view and positioning is done in storyboard

Comment: @AdamJohns then I think you should probably check your layout in the storyboard, I bet your autolayout constraints aren't quite what you think they are.

Comment: @RonLugge how exactly do I do that? I'm not too familiar with autolayout.

Comment: Click on the object, go the pane on the right, and bring up the 'size' inspector.  Despite it's name, if you scroll down you should see the layout you've defined.  What may be going on is that you don't have a specific height and width defined, but rather a distance from other objects -- and that distance is producing 'funky' results when those objects shift.

Comment: @RonLugge I added more images showing my scene and size inspector tab. I'm not sure how to tell if I am specifying a distance from other objects?

Comment: @AdamJohns you're specifying a height, a top space to superview, a leading space to superview, and a trailing space to superview.  You're also specifying a center-x to the button, but that will really only center the button, you've already locked the table's position in place.  What I find interesting is that it looks like your tableview is underlapping the status bar, or is that an illusion in the picture above?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is obviously some kind of issue with the grouped table view style. All I had to to was go into the storyboard scene, select the table view, then in the attributes inspector change the style from grouped to plain. It works as intended now without being cut off.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, more of a work-around.  I believe the answer suggested by unspokenblabber is the actual answer

Comment: Fair enough, it ended up being the issue on my app.  My point was that   changing the style of the table isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 6):

try playing with `navigationBar.translucent` property in your view controller. in `iOS 6` it is `NO` by default, but `YES` in `iOS 7`. I had a similar issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed this problem for me, but does anyone have an idea why this property set to `YES` would cause the bottom of a tableview to be cut off? The frame of my tableview is initialized with the view's frame, added to the view's subview, and there's no other views.

Comment: One reason could be a constrained height.  The top y being where the  nav starts could push the bottom down in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your `UITableView` frame in iOS7, may be you are running it on 3.5 inch view and it will shrink.

Comment: i'm running on 4 inch and even if i make the frame bigger it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the provided image, I think you may be underlapping the nav bar.  Or to put it another way, your nav bar is on top of hte table.  Though I'm not sure why that would cut off the bottom of the login information

Comment: no, the underlapping is not the issue, as I have already taken care of the underlapping successfully by using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that simply changing from GROUPED to PLAIN table view style fixes the "underlap" issue with the section #0 header, but modifies the color of the section header views. I set the tableview background color in my app. With PLAIN style, the section header background color is messed up. The section header color is close to the tableview background color, but slightly modified. This does NOT happen if I simply switch back to GROUPED. It sounds like an iOS7 bug or an Xcode bug.

Answer (score 0):

The translucent = NO fixed it for some cases.  In others, I ended up adjusting the tableView in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 CGRect f = self.tableView.frame;
 f.origin.y += self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
 f.size.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
 self.tableView.frame = f;
}
```