# Table View not stretching vertically iPhone 6

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

**The tableview isn't stretching all the way vertically in iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus.**

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

**Storyboard:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
This question was actually really helpful in another thing to check for as to why the tableview was getting cut off: [Why is my UITableView cut off in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129918/why-is-my-uitableview-cut-off-in-ios-7)

[image]

There's a whole bunch of things you want to check for if your Table View Cell are getting cut off:
 - are they pinned to superview or content view?
 - are the constraints such that you are cutting off content without knowing it? 
 - is a navigation bar or tab bar cutting off content?
 - check the auto resizing mask or add one if need be `settingsTable.autoresizingMask &= ~UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;`
[image]
[image]

And multiple other reasons.  Its tricky, so if you come across this Q+A and need help, just drop a note and will help!

Comment: What do your autolayout constraints look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your `tableView` and pres `Pin` (a litte square icon with lines on the sides down in Xcode). Then add the bottom constraint (click here, it will turn red) and set value 0. Enjoy

[image]