# ios 7 status bar and navigation bar issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7

My app's view is overlapped with status bar and navigationBar in ios7 device so I tried lots of solutions

- uncheck 'under top bars' property in storyboard
- self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
- set delta y to -20 in storyboard...

but none of these worked.
My last trial was adding these lines to appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
} else {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
}
```

It works quite well when navigation bar is hidden but when nagivigation is not hidden, 
navigationbar's frame is (0, 20, 320, 44) not (0, 0, 320, 44) 
So navigationBar's height seems to be 64..
why is this? Hope someone explains me!
Thanks is advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: @EclipseKim Please check out the guide I've provided and let me know if further information is required. If the guide is enough to assist you please feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a better explanation of the differences please see this transition guide ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set this in viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the overlapping with the `UINavigationBar`, you must set its `translucent` property to `NO`.

As for the status bar, you have to manually set it by specifying its style and then reposition the whole window's frame. I would add on top of that an iOS 7 condition to make sure that only happen with users running iOS 7.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height - 20); 
}
```