# unable to solve ios7 status bar issue

Tags: ios, ios7, uistatusbar

Before io7 my view show perfect result to me just like [image: io6 view]

but in ios7 status bar overlap to my view content like this [image: io7 view]

before i go through googling i found one solution that sat delta property of the view in Xcode 5.
i completed that. but still same issue. just like [image: property][image: set Delta]

please don't give me suggestion like hide status bar.
I am not using storyboard.
i am not using auto layout

i refered [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) link unable to find answer.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

I did below code for solving this problem.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
    viewBounds.origin.y = topBarOffset * -1;
    self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

please refer this 
  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7?rq=1) for further info

Comment: its not working for me. did you worked?

Comment: yes it did work for me, try using autolayout in Xcode 5 with iOS 7, just tick the autolayout option in Xcode.

Comment: buddy i don't using autolayout. bcz project run 5.0 and above

Comment: This only works if it's in a navigation controller.

Comment: Check if you are doing this on right UIViewController

Comment: There is no way to preserve the iOS 6 style status bar layout. The status bar will always overlap your application on iOS 7. Read apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html or this guide to get the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style