# Set UIWindow and UIview's Frame in storyboard in IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I have an application which has storyboard.
it works completely fine in 480 frame size of height.
but now i am converting it to 568 frame size for IOS 7 then it is not working.

The **self.window.frame.size.height** and **self.view.frame.size.height** is also coming 480 and its also coming in middle of the view.

It looks like this...

[image]

I am trying first time storyboard.
I changed programmatically the height of **Window** and **View** but its not working.
I tried below method in viewDidLoad but its not working too for this case

```
  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
  {
      self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
  }
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried other options of Delta, under top bar see other answers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7

Comment: Add launch image for retina & non-retina display and see your window will have proper height as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Problem...
i just left the image named "Default-568h@2x.png" in my project bundle for Launch Image.
and after putting this the problem solved.
I am putting this for others...
Thank you guys for your time.