# iOS StatusBar hide causes view controller to shift up

Tags: ios

I have a full screen navigation menu that covers the entire screen. The problem I am facing is when I try to hide the status using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

The status bar hides but the view controller seems to shift up.

My view controller has this property set:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
```

I thought that means the view controller's view appear underneath the status bar, regardless of the visibility of the status bar, the view controller should remain the same size, no ?

Is there a way to hide the status bar without affecting the height of the view controller's view ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems like a stupid mistake on my part.

My View Controller should be using:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Instead of

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
```

Comment: Strange thing, but the opposite (UIRectEdgeAll) did work for me.

Comment: In Swift 4 it's `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []` because there is no `.none` enum. This may be helpful to some people.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4!

If you are using `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false`, and are using something that uses UIScrollView, UICollectionView, etc., then doing

`yourScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

will prevent its contents from shifting.