# UITableViewCell.frame's y origin equals to 0 when navigation bar translucent set to false

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

On my main view controller is laid out a `UITableView` just under the navigation bar.

In my `AppDelegate`, I do some setup for the navigation bar in general as following:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)

let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navigationBarAppearace.barStyle = .Black
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

With this setup, when I call this on my first cell of my table view in my main view controller

```
let cellFrame = tableView.convertRect(cell.frame, toView: tableView.superview)
```

I get the following `frame`:

```
cellFrame : (0.0, 64.0, 375.0, 268.0)
```

Which is what I expect to get. Then, when I add the following in my setup in my `AppDelegate`:

```
navigationBarAppearace.translucent = false
```

then I get the following `frame`:

```
cellFrame : (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 268.0)
```

The y origin is now 0.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7?rq=1](this) may help you.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. My `tableView.frame.minY` still equals 0

Comment: My bad, I didn't try all the possibilities. Doing `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` in viewDidLoad of my main view controller fixed it. Which is weird as they say the opposite in the doc: `If your design uses opaque bars, refine edgesForExtendedLayout by also setting the extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars property to NO`