# Which is better storyboard or xib?

Tags: ios

I am a amateur ios developer. I am confused in using xib .could anyone please tell me when to use xib and when to use storyboard.I want to know differences between storyboard and xib.

Comment: See also: [What are the benefits of using Storyboards instead of xib files in iOS programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083759/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-storyboards-instead-of-xib-files-in-ios-programmi) and [When to use Storyboard and when to use XIBs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404471/when-to-use-storyboard-and-when-to-use-xibs)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before posting new question, please search on SO for related questions. There is a fair chance the question is already asked and answered, as in this case. Posting duplicate question is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt its **StoryBoard**.

People are a bit complacent adapting to storyboard for XIB usage. Except for that reason, Storyboard was designed to serve the purpose of UI with much ease.

Answer (score 0):

Really there is no one best, xib are a little more difficult to maintain because there are separated files, while storyboards give you a better view of the app flow... Making views in code I think can give you a very big headache if you want to change something in the future. So apple also recommends the use of storyboards, that is other important think to keep in mind.