# Storyboard or Xib in a multiple developer project

Tags: xcode, merge, xib, uistoryboard

I am working in a multiple developer native iOS app project.
Both developers need to access and modify UI elements so which one do you think is better to use; Storyboards or Xibs? I read some documents and some of them put Xibs over Storyboards as Storyboards can have lots of conflicts on merging the UI components but xibs have more independent structure.

Do you know any tools or appropriate ways to do that?

Our approach for now is to use 'multiple storyboards' and cut them clean so that the developers wouldn't need to modify each others storyboards. What do you think about this approach?

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go too deep into it, but both are fine. Especially if you do it in Xcode 5 and above, the format of xib/Storyboard file is much more version control friendly.

Use Storyboard if the interaction in your applications are quite simple and linear. Use xib files if many elements are reusable. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084124/361247) for more in depth explanation.