# IOS design from Storyboard or Code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I've noticed some developers choose to create their UI in code rather than in storyboards or nibs; are there any advantages or disadvantages to either?

Which should I use to architect my app?

Comment: Might be help you : https://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as per the requirement. You can use anyone of them or do partially from both of them. Main motive of developer is to give best `UI interaction` to the user. You can go with any one of these which is suitable for you.

Have a look : [What are the benefits of using Storyboards instead of xib files in iOS programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083759/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-storyboards-instead-of-xib-files-in-ios-programmi)

and

this [user-interface-programming](https://www.ackee.cz/en/blog/user-interface-programming-on-ios-at-ackee-storyboards-vs-xib-vs-code/)

You will get better better on this two links. If further you have issues and doubts you can ask.