# How do I create an IiPhone/iPad app which targets iOS 4.3 and later?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created an app using `Xcode 4.3` and `iOS 5.0`, but I recently found out I need to also support `4.3.x` devices.  I changed my Deployment target to 4.3, but then I got the infamous storyboard error:

> Storyboards are unavailable on `iOS 4.3` and prior

So, how do I create an app that targets both?  I can get my app to build using the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781483/ios5-storyboard-error-storyboards-are-unavailable-on-ios-4-3-and-prior) but then my app shows the launch screen and then goes blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Storyboard is only available on iOS 5.0 or higher.

If you want to support iOS 4.3 you need to remove all the storyboard code and go back to using not nib/viewcontroller way of building your UI.

Comment: So I can't have a project with a storyboard and a nib and detect it at runtime?

Comment: the only way you could do that is have a XIB file for when the user is using anything lower than iOS 5.0 and the storyboard when the user is

Comment: You could, check in the start and dann load the nib version of you app, but that would mean make two copies of the same app. You could just use the `NIB` version on iOS 5. Thus not using Store boarding at all.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I need to convert the app to not use story boards, since I am just starting, what is the best way to convert it?

Comment: First of all i will suggest you to not to remove the storyboard just let it be there. you can create the separate nib file and may call based on os version condition. Well i have the same issue where i had to take decision whether i should make my app to support for both iOS version then later i decide to build for iOS5.0 strictly.