# Minimum version for Storyboards in xcode iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, version, uistoryboard, minimum

I am working on Storyboards.I need to know the minimum version of ios that i can set befor making the Build and submit on App store.Can i use ios 4.0 as a target.Will it run on version below ios 5...?
Is there any solution to it.?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vikas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may have seen the following error message:
`Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior`
but however, Updating Xcode to the latest version (4.3.1) does not help either.

Here is a trick to modify the project for storyboards:
[iOS5 Storyboard error: Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781483/ios5-storyboard-error-storyboards-are-unavailable-on-ios-4-3-and-prior)

```
>Open XXXXXX.storyboard
>
>Open Identity and Type tag in your right view of Xcode.
>
>Set the value of Development in Document Versioning to "Xcode 4.2" (my default value is "Default Version (Xcode 4.1)".
>
>Change the value of Deployment from Project SDK Version (iOS 5.0) to iOS 5.0, then back to Project SDK Version (iOS 5.0)
```

Comment: HI i have tried this so many times but it occurs again randomly.Any idea what causes it to happen.?

Comment: I think that because Xcode would change it back for you some time, and you need to change it back. You can try to write a replacement script to relive the repeating jobs.

Comment: Although there is a version 4.3 of Xcode, and a version 4.3 of iOS, they aren't the same thing. Xcode 4.3 works with iOS 5.1. Xcode 4.2 shipped with the iOS 5.0 SDK and was the first release that supported storyboards. Make sure you aren't mixing up these similar but different version numbers.

Answer (score 6):

iOS 5.0 is what introduced Storyboard capabilities.

If you look on this Apple page:

[iOS 5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/)

"Storyboards" is one of the fine new features they introduced with this OS.  It is ***not*** backwards compatible.

If you want to support iOS 4, you must use good ol' XIB files (which will also work in iOS 5 & newer).