# Minimum version of Windows for Centennial Apps

Tags: desktop-bridge

What is the minimum version of Windows to be able to run Centennial Apps from the Windows Store?

Comment: @closevoter See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915488/what-is-minimum-version-of-google-play-services-to-use-firebase) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877160/minimum-version-for-storyboards-in-xcode-iphone) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Minimum version of Windows to use desktop bridge apps is **Windows 10 Anniversary Update**. This is **Version 1607** (OS Build **14393**). This is because desktop-bridge requires containers feature which is only available since Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

Keep in mind however that developer can target higher version of Windows through MinVersion field under TargetDeviceFamily tag inside AppxManifest.xml.

Here is example of targeting Windows 10 Anniversary Update:

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#make-sure-that-your-system-can-run-the-converter

http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-anniversary-update-project-centennial-apps-store

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any source for that?

Comment: @ispiro No problem :) Yes, I have added link to Desktop App Converter doc where there is a statement about requirements.

Comment: The link only refers to the DAC, not to running Centennial apps on the target machine.

Comment: @ispiro Yes, so I have also added another source which clearly states: "The launch of the Windows 10 Anniversary Update on August 2 will include official support for releasing Win32 apps via the Windows Store with the Project Centennial Bridge tools."

Comment: Thanks. That really says that. I'm still looking for a source from Microsoft, though. Also, I see that Evernote on the Windows Store (which i believe is a Centennial app) has Windows 8 as the OS requirement (which, granted, doesn't make sense).

Comment: @ispro Hmm it does make an interesting case. Maybe someone from MS will show up here :)

Comment: I'm hoping for that. I wonder why such basic information is nowhere to be found.