# storyboards are unavailable on ios 4.3 and prior

Tags: iphone, xcode

i've developing the iphone application. i got a error when i run the application like "**storyboards are unavailable on ios 4.3 and prior**". i don't know how to resolve this so anyone guide me to resolve this.

My xcode is 4.3 version. My iphone is 2g.

Comment: storyboard is not available on ios version older than ios 5, maybe you are running your app on iPhone device with os older than ios5

Answer (score 4):

Did you do ANY research on this question? Storyboards are only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later.

If you build an application that is based on storyboards, you must choose 5.0 as the least supported iOS version on your build settings.

And vice versa, if you want to build your application for 4.3, you must not use storyboards.

Comment: oh ok ok. not use storyboards means i cant understand please tell clearly.

Comment: @user1481662 Please take time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially regarding asking questions and searching before asking questions. We are here to help you, not to do your work for you. Apple provide a large number of documents on all aspects of development for a reason. READ THEM.

Comment: @NickBull how do you add href links in comments?

Comment: @PauldeLange When you add a comment, click the "help" that appears just under the "Add Comment" button. It will show you the mini-markdown formatting

Comment: Oh cool! Sorry to everybody who has had to read my plaintext comments up until now.

Comment: can i run my iphone application with out storyboard?

Comment: Yes, please read the Apple Development Guidelines first and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer here at [iOS5 Storyboard error: Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781483/ios5-storyboard-error-storyboards-are-unavailable-on-ios-4-3-and-prior)

Storyboards are not supported for IOS 4.3.